# Why is this NodeJS 2x faster than native C?

Tags: c, node.js, performance, optimization

For the sake of a presentation at work, I wanted to compare the performance of NodeJS to C. Here is what I wrote:

Node.js (for.js):

```
var d = 0.0,
    start = new Date().getTime();

for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
  d += i >> 1;
}

var end = new Date().getTime();

console.log(d);
console.log(end - start);
```

C (for.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main () {
  clock_t start = clock();

  long d = 0.0;

  for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
  {
    d += i >> 1;    
  }

  clock_t end = clock();
  clock_t elapsed = (end - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000); 

  printf("%ld\n", d);
  printf("%lu\n", elapsed);
}
```

Using GCC I compiled my `for.c` and ran it:

```
gcc for.c
./a.out
```

Results:

```
2499999950000000
198
```

Then I tried it in NodeJS:

```
node for.js
```

Results:

```
2499999950000000
116
```

After running numerous times, I discovered this held true no matter what. If I switched for.c to use a `double` instead of a `long` in the loop, the time C took was even longer!

Not trying to start a flame war, but why is Node.JS (116 ms.) so much faster than native C (198 ms.) at performing this same operation? Is Node.JS applying an optimization that GCC does not do out of the box?

**EDIT:**

Per suggestion in comments, I ran `gcc -Wall -O2 for.c`. Results improved to C taking 29 ms. This begs the question, how is it that the native C settings are not optimized as much as a Javascript compiler? Also, what is -Wall and -02 doing. I'm really curious about the details of what is going on here.

Comment: Try to compile with `gcc -Wall -O2 for.c` and benchmark again. Using `gcc` (or `clang`) without passing any explicit optimization flag for benchmarking is useless!

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting different optimization levels when compiling the C program?

Comment: `long d = 0.0;` -- isn't `long` an integer type?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with C optimization. I'll give any suggestions a shot!

Comment: @Jongware apologies, I originally had it `double d = 0.0` and C was even slower. Forgot to switch to `0L`.

Comment: You're measuring wall time in Node.js and CPU time in C.

Comment: Measure again compiling with: `gcc -march=native -O2 for.c` (I get 260 with your compiler flags and 98 with mine! Even just `-O1` reduces the run time to less than half.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I could see that being an issue if this was only a couple milliseconds, but we are talking a couple hundred milliseconds. Would it still matter? I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: `-march=native -02` and `-Wall -02` have the same results: roughly 29 ms. That is more the type of performance I was expecting from C.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh, sorry miscommunication. I was referring to your comment regarding CPU vs wall time. It's possible I don't understand optimizations that well but I do have experience writing loop unrolling in native assembly so I do get some of it :P

Comment: In this kind of toy benchmark you could even see 100M times speedup on the loop, since it is quite possible to make optimization that changes this kind of loop to closed formula and then propagate constants. That wouldn't prove superiority of any compiler, since this kind of loop is unlikely to happen in any optimized code.

Comment: @zch superiority isn't exactly my point here. I guess I was just expecting that out-of-the-box GCC should show some performance improvement over a scripting language. I was just pleasantly surprised at how well the V8 engineers must have done if the results were in the same order of magnitude.

Comment: Well, the v8 engine isn't an interpreter either, it does compile the code (and optimizing it on the fly where possible).

Comment: @mscdex So truthfully the reason I asked the question was because I thought I had written my C code wrong or something. I did not expect, in my wildest dreams, for Node.JS to perform that well. As a comparison, I ran the same thing in Ruby and it took 9.3 seconds. That's nearly 100x slower that Node.JS. I was just not expecting these results.

Comment: The short answer is that when you don't specify any optimization, gcc doesn't do *any* optimization. It just generates code as quickly as it can, regardless of how slow it'll run. Compiling C (and C++) tends to be slow enough that for most development, most people just want to get something that runs as soon as possible, regardless of how slow that runs. Only when the code is at least close to finished, they turn on the optimizer and put up with slower compile times.

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin. At first that surprised me but the more I thought about it, it makes sense. For something like C I imagine the powers that be wanted everything to be incredibly configurable. Not only that, but I'm sure it's quite helpful for C students to be able to spit spit out the Assembly or machine code in a non-optimized way and then to crank up the optimization as they learn to see how it changes the output. Appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: Nobody knows whats inside that Node.js engine. Maybe it is using SIMD instructions to parallelize this for() loop in many threads. If that is the case, writing in for specific hardware in C with SIMD will by far outrun Node.js

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*This begs the question, how is it that the native C settings are not optimized as much as a Javascript compiler?*

Since C is statically-compiled and linked, requiring a potentially lengthy build step of your entire codebase (I once worked in one that took almost an hour for a full optimized build, but only 10 minutes otherwise), and a very dangerous, hardware-level language that risks a lot of undefined behaviors if you don't treat it with care, the default settings of compilers usually don't optimize to smithereens since that's a developer/debug build intended to help with debugging and productivity with faster turnaround.

So in C you get a distinct separation between an unoptimized but faster-to-build, easier-to-debug *developer/debug* build and a very optimized, slower-to-build, harder-to-debug *production/release* build that runs really fast, and the default settings of compilers often favor the former.

With something like v8/NodeJS, you're dealing with a just-in-time compiler (dynamic compilation) that builds and optimizes only the necessary code on the fly at run-time. On top of that, JS is a much safer language and also often designed for security that doesn't allow you to work at the raw bits and bytes of the hardware.

As a result, it doesn't need that kind of strong release/debug build distinction of a native, statically-compiled language like C/C++. But it also doesn't let you put the pedal to the metal as you can in C if you really want.

A lot of people trying to benchmark C/C++ coming from other languages often fail to understand this build distinction and the importance of compiler/linker optimization settings and get confused. As you can see, with the proper settings, it's hard to beat the performance of these native compilers and languages that allow you to write really low-level code.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the register key word helps as expected

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main () {
  register long i, d;
  clock_t start = clock();
  i = d = 0L;

  for (i = 0; i < 100000000L; i++) {
    d += i >> 1;
  }

  clock_t end = clock();
  clock_t elapsed = (end - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);

  printf("%ld\n", d);
  printf("%lu\n", elapsed);
}
```

and compile with the C compiler

```
 cc     for.c   -o for

./for ; node for.js
```

returns

```
2499999950000000
97
2499999950000000
222
```

Comment: Interesting, I was reading recently that `register` anymore, however, is not much better than any of the `-OX` options. But it makes sense. Nice post.

Answer (score 1):

I've also done some testing calculating prime numbers and I've found that Node.js is about twice as fast as C [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360403/how-can-node-js-be-faster-than-c-and-java-benchmark-comparing-node-js-c-java).

When you have a very simple counting type of loop, the -O2 optimization can sometimes convert the output to a simple formula without even iterating the loop.  See [Karl's Blog](http://karlheinzniebuhr.github.io/en/2015/09/28/C-vs-Go-vs-pypy-vs-Python/) for an explination.  If you add something more complicated to the routine it is likely node.js will be faster again.  for example I added a devisor term into your sample program and the c -O2 optimization was no longer able to convert it to a simple formula and node.js became faster again.

I am still baffled as to how node.js can be caster than c at simple integer calculations, but in every test I've done so far it is faster.  I've also performed some tests with bitwise calculations that I haven't posted yet and still node.js was faster.

Answer (score -1):

node.js and C are distinct in that node.js is interpreting JavaScript whereas C is compiling code to machine language. As such, both are handled differently. For node.js, you simply run the .js file. C is much different from this. When you are compiling code to machine language using GCC, you must supply compiler optimization settings aka "flags." Your node.js program is actually slower than the C program if you specify the -O3 flag to GCC. In fact, the node.js program took twice as long for me as the C program did. You stated that you would like to know more about what the C compiler does to optimize code. This is a complex topic/field and I highly recommend reading [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) on compiler optimization to learn more.

In short, you made an unfair comparison because you did not optimize your C code.

Comment: Actually, NodeJS is compiled, not interpreted- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103939/does-node-js-compile-javascript