# How can node.js be faster than c and java? Benchmark comparing node.js, c, java and python

Tags: java, python, c, node.js

I made a very simple benchmarking program that calculates all the prime numbers up to 10,000,000 in 4 different languages.

- (2.97 seconds) - node.js (javascript) (4.4.5)
- (6.96 seconds) - c (c99)
- (6.91 seconds) - java (1.7)
- (45.5 seconds) - python (2.7)

*above is average of 3 runs each, user time*

Node.js runs by far the fastest.  This is confusing to me for two reasons:

1. javascript always uses double precision floats for variables while c and java are using (long) integers in this case.  Math with integers should be faster.
2. javascript is often referred to as interpreted when actually it is a just in time compiled language.  But even so how can the JIT compiler be faster than a fully compiled language? 
   The python code runs the slowest which is no surprise, but why isn't the node.js code running at a similar speed to the python?

I compiled the c code with -O2 optimization, but I tried it with all levels of optimization and it didn't make a noticeable difference.

### countPrime.js

```
"use strict";

var isPrime = function(n){
    //if (n !== parseInt(n,10)) {return false};
    if (n < 2) {return false};
    if (n === 2) {return true};
    if (n === 3) {return true};
    if (n % 2 === 0) {return false};
    if (n % 3 === 0) {return false};
    if (n % 1) {return false};
    var sqrtOfN = Math.sqrt(n);
    for (var i = 5; i <= sqrtOfN; i += 6){
        if (n % i === 0) {return false}
        if (n % (i + 2) === 0) {return false}
    }
    return true;
};

var countPrime = function(){
    var count = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < 10000000;i++){
        if (isPrime(i)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    console.log('total',count);
};

countPrime();
```

### node.js results

```
$ time node primeCalc.js
total 664579

real    0m2.965s
user    0m2.928s
sys     0m0.016s

$ node --version
v4.4.5
```

### primeCalc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

int isPrime (register long n){
    if (n < 2)      return false;
    if (n == 2)     return true;
    if (n == 3)     return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
    if (n % 3 == 0) return false;
    if (n % 1)      return false;
    double sqrtOfN = sqrt(n);
    for (long i = 5; i <= sqrtOfN; i += 6){
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
        if (n % (i + 2) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    register long count = 0;
    for (register long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
        if (isPrime(i)){
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("total %li\n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

### c results

```
$ gcc primeCalc.c -lm -g -O2 -std=c99 -Wall
$ time ./a.out
total 664579
real    0m6.718s
user    0m6.668s
sys     0m0.008s
```

### PrimeCalc.java

public class PrimeCalc {

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     long count = 0;
     for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
        if (isPrime(i)){
           count++;
        }
     }
     System.out.println("total "+count);
  }


  public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
     if (n < 2)      return false;
     if (n == 2)     return true;
     if (n == 3)     return true;
     if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
     if (n % 3 == 0) return false;
     if (n % 1 > 0)  return false;
     double sqrtOfN = Math.sqrt(n);
     for (long i = 5; i <= sqrtOfN; i += 6){
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
        if (n % (i + 2) == 0) return false;
     }
     return true;
  };

}
```

### java results

```
 $ javac PrimeCalc.java 
 $ time java PrimeCalc
 total 664579
 real    0m7.197s
 user    0m7.036s
 sys     0m0.040s
 $ java -version
 java version "1.7.0_111"
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

### primeCalc.py

```
import math

def isPrime (n):
    if n < 2       : return False
    if n == 2      : return True
    if n == 3      : return True
    if n % 2 == 0  : return False
    if n % 3 == 0  : return False
    if n % 1 >0    : return False
    sqrtOfN = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
    for i in xrange (5, sqrtOfN, 6):
        if n % i == 0       : return False;
        if n % (i + 2) == 0 : return False;
    return True

count = 0;
for i in xrange(10000000) :
    if isPrime(i) :
        count+=1

print "total ",count
```

### python results

```
time python primeCalc.py
total  664579
real    0m46.588s
user    0m45.732s
sys     0m0.156s 
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

### linux

```
$ uname -a
Linux hoarfrost-node_6-3667558 4.2.0-c9 #1 SMP Wed Sep 30 16:14:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### additional c run times (addendum)

- (7.81 s) no optimization, gcc primeCalc.c -lm -std=c99 -Wall
- (8.13 s) optimization 0, gcc primeCalc.c -lm -O0 -std=c99 -Wall
- (7.30 s) optimization 1, gcc primeCalc.c -lm -O1 -std=c99 -Wall
- (6.66 s) optimization 2, gcc primeCalc.c -lm -O2 -std=c99 -Wall

  - average of 3 new runs each optimization level user time *

I read the post here:
[Why is this NodeJS 2x faster than native C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432973/why-is-this-nodejs-2x-faster-than-native-c)
This code uses an example that doesn't actually do anything significant.    It's as if the compiler can figure out the result at compile time and it doesn't even need to execute the loop 100000000 times to come up with the answer.
If one adds another division step to the calculation the optimization is much less significant.

```
for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
  d += i >> 1;    
  d = d / (i +1); // <-- New Term 
}
```

- (1.88 seconds) without optimization
- (1.53 seconds) with optimization (-O2)

---

**Update 03/15/2017**
After reading the answer from @leon I ran a few verification tests.

**Test 1 - 32 Bit Beaglebone Black, 664,579 primes up to 10,000,000**

Unedited calcPrime.js and calcPrime.c running on the Beaglebone black which has a 32 bit processor.

- C code = 62 seconds   (gcc, long datatype)
- JS code = 102 seconds  (node v4)

**Test 2 - 64 Bit Macbook Pro, 664,579 primes up to 10,000,000**

Replace long datatypes in calcPrime.c code with uint32_t and running on my MacBook pro which has a 64 bit processor.

- C code = 5.73 seconds (clang, long datatype)
- C code = 2.43 seconds (clang, uint_32_t datatype)
- JS code = 2.12 seconds (node v4)

**Test 3 - 64 Bit Macbook Pro, 91,836 primes (i=1; i < 8,000,000,000; i+=10000)**

Use unsigned long datatypes in C code, force javascript to use some 64 bit.
 - C code = 20.4 seconds (clang, long datatype) 
 - JS code = 17.8 seconds (node v4)

**Test 4 - 64 Bit Macbook Pro, 86,277 primes (i = 8,000,00,001; i < 16,000,000,000; i+=10000)**

Use unsigned long datatypes in C code, force javascript to use all 64 bit.
 - C code = 35.8 seconds (clang, long datatype) 
 - JS code = 34.1  seconds (node v4)

**Test 5 - Cloud9 64-Bit Linux, (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)**

```
language    datatype    time    % to C
javascript  auto        3.22      31%
C           long        7.95     224%
C           int         2.46       0%
Java        long        8.08     229%
Java        int         2.15     -12%
Python      auto       48.43    1872%
Pypy        auto        9.51     287%
```

**Test 6 - Cloud9 64-Bit Linux, (i = 8000000001; i < 16000000000;i+=10000)**

```
javascript  auto       52.38      12%
C           long       46.80       0%
Java        long       49.70       6%
Python      auto      268.47     474%
Pypy        auto       56.55      21%
```

(All results are the average of the user seconds for three runs, time variation between runs < 10%)

**Mixed Results**

Changing the C and Java datatype to integer when in the range of integers significantly sped up execution.  On the BBB and Cloud9 computers switching to ints made C faster than node.js.  But on my Mac the node.js program still ran faster.  Perhaps because the Mac is using clang and the BBB and Cloud 9 computers are using gcc.  Does anyone know if gcc compiles faster programs than gcc?

When using all 64 bit integers C was a bit faster than node.js on the BBB and Cloud9 PC but a little slower on my MAC.

You can also see that pypy is about four times faster than standard python in these tests.

The fact that node.js is even compatible to C amazes me.

Comment: [v8](http://jayconrod.com/posts/54/a-tour-of-v8-crankshaft-the-optimizing-compiler) is *optimizing*. In fact, *v8* is **very** *optimizing*. However, ***beware*** micro-benchmarks.

Comment: maybe you are putting a finger onto something with the `long` to `double` conversion, these might be costly on the long run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this NodeJS 2x faster than native C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432973/why-is-this-nodejs-2x-faster-than-native-c)

Comment: @enRaiser Here, `gcc` is being passed `-O2` already.

Comment: I wonder if using `-m64` to force a 64-bit build would make a difference? v8 can probably optimise for the current processor, but without flags gcc is building a generic executable for the whole x86 family?

Comment: -O2 -m64 dropped the average on three runs from 6.66 to 6.41 seconds, but the results vary by a couple of tenths of a second each time so I can't say it actually had any significant result.

Comment: Is there a more representative benchmark or a standard benchmark that can be used in these languages?

Comment: Compile C code with -msse4.2 option and check if the results improve

Comment: Remove the register keywords and install the latest version of gcc.

Comment: @dvhh You're right, the conversion of i to double on each iterations costs about 20%.

Comment: On my AMD A8-5500: gcc 5.4.0 -- 4.5 s; nodejs 4.2.6 -- 4.7 s

Comment: It feels like that squareroot is giving js an unfair edge, because it only knows doubles as @dvhh noted.You might want to see if letting them all use a truncated long integer squareroot that pulls out no real operations might make it closer. Here is such a function that uses the fact that sum of the first n odd numbers is n^2. var truncSqrt=function(n){
var oddNumber=1;
var result=0;
while (n>=oddNumber)
{n-=oddNumber;
oddNumber+=2;
result++;
}
return result;
}//wrote in js, freshest for me

Comment: Related question : https://www.quora.com/How-can-the-performance-of-Node-js-be-better-than-Java-Python-PHP-or-C

Comment: The call to sqrt is actually completely unnecessary. You could replace the test with `i*i<=n`, for example. And what on earth is the point of `if (n % 1)      return false;`? If n is an integer, `n%1` is never true (and in C, `%` is only defined for integer arguments).

Comment: I tried changing the sort to i*i <= n as @rici suggested.  The execution time for the c code went from 6.66 to 7.22 seconds.  I think this is because the sqrt() is only called once each isPrime(), where as the i*i is calculated each pass of the for loop.  I profiled this program in Xcode on a different computer and found that the sqrt() is only 0.02% of the execution time.  This is because the sqrt() is only called once for each isPrime() call and only if the other tests prior to it fail to catch a non prime number.  This seems to rule out sqrt().

Comment: I had to modify the program somewhat to get a profile of where the execution is taking place

Comment: I had to modify the program somewhat to get a profile of where the execution is taking place. 52.5% inside the for loop of isPrime(), 47.1% in isPrime() just prior to the for loop with the if statments and < 0.1% calculating the sqrt and about 0.3% in main.  My conclusion is that sqrt is not skewing the results.

Comment: I tried the -msse4.2 parameter as @Nulik suggested.  Execution time dropped from 6.66 to 6.62 seconds.

Comment: @timothy: yes, the problem isn't really the sqrt but rather the conversion from int to float (unless the compiler optimizes it away). But it's not going be a big difference. I'd suggest getting rid of all those tests at the entry to isPrime by starting with `if (n < 6) switch n) ...` That won't help much, but it is at least noticeable.

Comment: @rici I put sqrt inside a function that returns a long and it made essentially no difference in execution time.  Is there another conversion from into to float with the modulus or something else?

Comment: @timothy: You don't need a function. C(++) will happily truncate a double to a long in an assignment operator. As I said, it won't make much difference (particularly on x86 hardware). For me, changing `i` from `long` to `unsigned int` made the most difference (about 15%). (This must be safe on x86 since the square root of a 63-bit signed long will definitely fit in a 32 unsigned int.) I also changed `sqrtOfN` to the same type, which made about 5% difference.

Comment: @Leon This question has been reopened.  You can submit your answer now.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I spent a couple of days investigating the performance difference between JS/V8 and C, focusing first of all on the Hydrogen IR generated by the V8 engine. However, after making sure that no extraordinary optimizations are present there, I got back to the analysis of the assembly output and it struck me that the answer was a very simple one, boiling down to the couple of sentences in [Jay Conrod's blog post](http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation) on internals of V8:

> According to the spec, all numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point doubles. We frequently work with integers though, so ***V8 represents numbers with 31-bit signed integers whenever possible***.

The example at hand allows fitting all computations in 32 bits and node.js takes full advantage of that! The C code utilizes the `long` type, which on OP's (as well as my) platform happens to be a 64-bit type. Thus, it is a 32-bit arithmetic vs 64-bit arithmetic issue, mostly due to the expensive division/remainder operation.

If `long` in the C code is replaced with `int`, then the binary produced by gcc beats node.js.

Also, if the loop is made to look for primes over a range that is outside the realm of 32-bit numbers the performance of the node.js version drops significantly.

---

### Proof

The used source code is found further in the answer, below the results.

> #### Counting primes less than 10 million with C and node.js

```
$ gcc count_primes.c -std=c99 -O3 -lm -o count_primes_long
$ sed 's/long/int/g; s/%li/%i/g' count_primes.c > count_primes_int.c
$ gcc count_primes_int.c -std=c99 -O3 -lm -o count_primes_int

# Count primes <10M using C code with (64-bit) long type
$ time ./count_primes_long 0 10000000
The range [0, 10000000) contains 664579 primes

real    0m4.394s
user    0m4.392s
sys 0m0.000s

# Count primes <10M using C code with (32-bit) int type
$ time ./count_primes_int 0 10000000
The range [0, 10000000) contains 664579 primes

real    0m1.386s
user    0m1.384s
sys 0m0.000s

# Count primes <10M using node.js/V8 which transparently does the
# job utilizing 32-bit types
$ time nodejs ./count_primes.js 0 10000000
The range [ 0 , 10000000 ) contains 664579 primes

real    0m1.828s
user    0m1.820s
sys 0m0.004s
```

> #### Performance figures in the vicinity of the limit of signed 32-bit integers

Counting the primes in the range of length 100,000 starting at the number contained in the first column:

```
              | node.js | C (long) 
-----------------------------------
2,000,000,000 | 0.293s  | 0.639s    # fully within the 32-bit range
-----------------------------------
2,147,383,647 | 0.296s  | 0.655s    # fully within the 32-bit range
-----------------------------------
2,147,453,647 | 2.498s  | 0.646s    # 50% within the 32-bit range
-----------------------------------
2,147,483,647 | 4.717s  | 0.652s    # fully outside the 32-bit range
-----------------------------------
3,000,000,000 | 5.449s  | 0.755s    # fully outside the 32-bit range
-----------------------------------
```

---

**count_primes.js**

```
"use strict";

var isPrime = function(n){
    if (n < 2) {return false};
    if (n === 2) {return true};
    if (n === 3) {return true};
    if (n % 2 === 0) {return false};
    if (n % 3 === 0) {return false};
    var sqrtOfN = Math.sqrt(n);
    for (var i = 5; i <= sqrtOfN; i += 6){
        if (n % i === 0) {return false}
        if (n % (i + 2) === 0) {return false}
    }
    return true;
};

var countPrime = function(S, E){
    var count = 0;
    for (let i = S; i < E;i++){
        if ( isPrime(i) ) { ++count; }
    }
    return count;
};

if( process.argv.length != 4) {
    console.log('Usage: nodejs count_prime.js <range_start> <range_length>');
    process.exit();
}

var S = parseInt(process.argv[2]);
var N = parseInt(process.argv[3]);
var E = S+N;
var P = countPrime(S, E);
console.log('The range [', S, ',', E, ') contains', P, 'primes');
```

---

**count_primes.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

int isPrime (register long n){
    if (n < 2)      return false;
    if (n == 2)     return true;
    if (n == 3)     return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
    if (n % 3 == 0) return false;
    double sqrtOfN = sqrt(n);
    for (long i = 5; i <= sqrtOfN; i += 6){
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
        if (n % (i + 2) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if ( argc != 3 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: count_primes <range_start> <range_length>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    const long S = atol(argv[1]);
    const long N = atol(argv[2]);
    register long count = 0;
    for (register long i = S; i < S + N; i++){
        if ( isPrime(i) ) ++count;
    }
    printf("The range [%li, %li) contains %li primes\n", S, S+N, count);
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for JS/V8 being faster than C?

Answer (score -1):

When I ran your code in python with a new algorithm:

```
real    0m3.583s
user    0m3.297s
sys     0m0.094s
```

Faster than the C benchmark you have above. I think that a simpler language helps you design better algorithms, but that is my opinion.
(Also can use multiprocessing to make even faster)

```
def allPrimes(N):
    is_prime = [1]*N
    # We know 0 and 1 are composites
    is_prime[0] = 0
    is_prime[1] = 0

    i = 2
    # This will loop from 2 to int(sqrt(x))
    while i*i <= N:
        # If we already crossed out this number, then continue
        if is_prime[i] == 0:
            i += 1
            continue

        j = 2*i
        while j < N:
            # Cross out this as it is composite
            is_prime[j] = 0
            # j is incremented by i, because we want to cover all multiples of i
            j += i

        i += 1
    return is_prime




print("total", sum(allPrimes(10000000)))
```

Comment: What's the benchmark of your algorithm in C? I think in this question we are comparing language speed, not algorithm speed. Of course one could write a better algorithm, but you need to benchmark using same algorithm in different languages. You cant use your time and compare it with op's algorithm time.