# Why is looping in nodejs faster than in c# (dotnet 6)

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, performance

I tried executing this loop for c# version 10

```
 long num = 0;
 for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
     num = num + i;
    }
 Console.WriteLine(num);
```

And after building the console app(**newapp**) using the dotnet CLI tool (**dotnet build**)
I measured the time it would take to execute the command by executing the **exe** compiled code of my console app using the code below:

```
Measure-Command { dotnet ./newapp.exe}
```

I got on the average this output

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 391
Ticks             : 3914079
TotalDays         : 4.53018402777778E-06
TotalHours        : 0.000108724416666667
TotalMinutes      : 0.006523465
TotalSeconds      : 0.3914079
TotalMilliseconds : 391.4079
```

And when I wrote this for nodejs:

```
var num=0;
for(let i = 0; i<100000000; i++){
    num=num+i;
}
console.log(num);
```

And I executed this:

```
 Measure-Command { node c.js}
```

I got on average the output below:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 346
Ticks             : 3462230
TotalDays         : 4.00721064814815E-06
TotalHours        : 9.61730555555555E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0.00577038333333333
TotalSeconds      : 0.346223
TotalMilliseconds : 346.223
```

So my question is why is it that nodejs execute faster on my machine. I thought the compiled c# should execute faster than nodejs. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you build it in release mode? (`dotnet build -c Release`) - although in reality, anything that lasts only a few hundred milliseconds: probably hard to be conclusive about

Comment: "Performance" isn't really something you can run once and fully trust the results. This also very much depends on how you compiled each app, how you run them, what versions of tools you're doing, and much more. Plus, you'd really want to analyse your claim on _a lot_ of computers to get an average.

Comment: Fair bet the C# JIT compiler spends quite a bit of resources optimizing things, too.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for correcting me. I've made changed to the nodejs execution command.

Comment: If you wrote that loop in C, an `-O3` build is likely to optimise the loop away completely. Comparing the performance of trivial code is hard.

Comment: @MarcGravell adding the -c Release didn't really cause any substantial change or change at all.

Comment: V8 will often optimize code by compiling it to an intermediate language, or sometimes even all the way to machine language, esp. for really simple/trivial code like this. So its not surprising to see it being very fast on super simple examples, but it is a bit surprising to see C# be relatively slow. That said, its impossible to draw any useful conclusions from these sorts of isolated and contrived synthetic benchmarks. Adding a few hundred thousand more iterations onto a simple loop does not make the test more reliable

Comment: do you have any small and relatively simple personal projects laying around that you could feasibly write in both languages, and that actually *do* something useful? comparing something like that, while it wouldnt be 100% conclusive, would at least be more illuminating.

Comment: Also see the accepted answer on this question for a sample of some of the gotchas that might come w/ comparing V8 JS and other compiled languages 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360403/how-can-node-js-be-faster-than-c-and-java-benchmark-comparing-node-js-c-java     ok i will shut up now :)

Comment: Thanks @diopside.. Nodejs seems to be quite fast though

Comment: compared to the javascript of a decade ago, it IS quite amazing how fast its gotten

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time is spent in the overhead of launching the process and printing, not the actual loop itself. You need to measure only the time of the loop run.

Also, JIT makes the first run a little slower, so you should probably benchmark the C# code with `BenchmarkDotNet`. I'm not sure what's the best alternative for nodejs though.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code in C#:

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Start: " + dt.ToLongTimeString());
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("End: " + dt2.ToLongTimeString());
        Console.WriteLine(dt2 - dt);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

and this in Javascript:

```
        var dt = Date.now();
        for(i=0;i<=1000000;i++){

        }
        var dt2 = Date.now();
        console.log(`Time: ${(dt2-dt)/1000}`);
```

the results were **0.011** for C# and **0.003** for Javascript
but when I changed **1000000 to 1000000000** the results were **0.9** for C# and **2.38** for JavaScript >>> It's strange.

Comment: Interesting !!! Seems like running the benchmark within the application gives you a better measurement

Answer (score 0):

This is too simplistic of a speed test.  A more complicated numerical processing algorithm would give more meaningful results.

It's literally compiling down to 25 machine instructions and that's too small of a sample to give a good comparison.

Comment: I actually looped through a larger number and nodejs seemed to be faster most times.